# .htaccess 404 redirect, but not in case of no images?

Tags: .htaccess, exception, http-redirect

There is a 404 redirect, working fine, but I'm looking for a solution in the .htaccess file to make an exception in case of images (jpg, gif, png, ...) not found.

Someone here with a possibility to do so?

Actual rule in the htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/
```

Best regards!

Comment: What's your current redirect rule/directive look like?

Comment: it's a simple 404 rule in my htaccess file: ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/

Comment: What do you want to happen if someone accesses an image that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that if an image is not found you want the user to see an image that has an error message instead of the default text page that is normally displayed. Here is how to do that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Add additional file extensions to the list as needed.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|tiff)$
RewriteRule (.*) /relative/location/of/errorimage.jpg
```

If there is something else you are trying to do, comment back and I'll adjust the example accordingly.

Comment: Hello Wige, I was trying to prevent the 404 redirect rule just for the case if a URL to an images wasn't found, but this is a great solution too, so I mark this as the correct answer! Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help. If you want to output a different error document, you can do that as well by putting the appropriate path in the rule.

Comment: There is one problem I just noticed, and that is that it will not return a status code of 404. The closest you might be able to do is add a [G] at the end of the last line above, which would return a 410 (Gone, will prevent search engines from cataloging the image). I am not absolutely sure it works, but it might.

Comment: Its okay for my project to not return a status code of 404, but I added the [G] if you think its better. It's for a community where users can upload photos to a private album, and their friends will receive a notification about that. Now I had the problem that the uploader can remove the photos again and after if a friend will click on the image notification link, then the nophoto.jpg appears now. That's better I think instead of redirecting the user to the main page because the image URL isn't found anymore. So, everything is fine now.